# How to show the desired region when using ListDensityPlot？

Tags: plotting

I plot a figure using ListDensityPlot. Where
As shown in the figure, there is no data in the marked rigion. But why is it still shown? How to fix that?

The code used here is

```
datadensity = Import["datadensity.csv"];
pdensity = 
 ListDensityPlot[datadensity, PlotRange -> All, 
  FrameLabel -> {Row[{Style["\[Epsilon]", 12], 
      Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(2\)]\)", 12]}], 
    Row[{Style["\[Alpha]", 12], 
      Style["/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Alpha]\), \(c\)]\)", 12]}]}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[12, Black]]
```

I don't know how to attach the whole data, so the sparse one is shown in the below. This may be useful. Sorry about that. Thank you so much.

```
datadensity ={{0.001, 1.4901, 1.}, {0.001, 1.9901, 1.}, {0.001, 2.4901, 
  1.}, {0.001, 2.9901, 1.}, {0.001, 3.4901, 1.}, {0.001, 3.9901, 
  1.}, {0.001, 4.4901, 1.}, {0.001, 4.9901, 1.}, {0.001, 5.4901, 
  1.}, {0.001, 5.9901, 1.}, {0.001, 6.4901, 1.}, {0.001, 6.9901, 
  1.}, {0.001, 7.4901, 1.}, {0.001, 7.9901, 1.}, {0.501, 1.4901, 
  1.}, {0.501, 1.9901, 1.}, {0.501, 2.4901, 1.}, {0.501, 2.9901, 
  1.}, {0.501, 3.4901, 1.}, {0.501, 3.9901, 1.}, {0.501, 4.4901, 
  1.}, {0.501, 4.9901, 1.}, {0.501, 5.4901, 1.}, {0.501, 5.9901, 
  1.}, {0.501, 6.4901, 1.}, {0.501, 6.9901, 1.}, {0.501, 7.4901, 
  1.}, {0.501, 7.9901, 1.}, {1.001, 1.4901, 1.}, {1.001, 1.9901, 
  1.}, {1.001, 2.4901, 1.}, {1.001, 2.9901, 1.}, {1.001, 3.4901, 
  1.}, {1.001, 3.9901, 1.}, {1.001, 4.4901, 1.}, {1.001, 4.9901, 
  1.}, {1.001, 5.4901, 1.}, {1.001, 5.9901, 1.}, {1.001, 6.4901, 
  1.}, {1.001, 6.9901, 1.}, {1.001, 7.4901, 1.}, {1.001, 7.9901, 
  1.}, {1.501, 1.4901, 1.}, {1.501, 1.9901, 1.}, {1.501, 2.4901, 
  1.}, {1.501, 2.9901, 1.}, {1.501, 3.4901, 1.}, {1.501, 3.9901, 
  1.}, {1.501, 4.4901, 1.}, {1.501, 4.9901, 1.}, {1.501, 5.4901, 
  1.}, {1.501, 5.9901, 1.}, {1.501, 6.4901, 1.}, {1.501, 6.9901, 
  1.}, {1.501, 7.4901, 1.}, {1.501, 7.9901, 1.}, {2.001, 1.4901, 
  1.00001}, {2.001, 1.9901, 1.00001}, {2.001, 2.4901, 
  1.00001}, {2.001, 2.9901, 1.00001}, {2.001, 3.4901, 
  1.00001}, {2.001, 3.9901, 1.00001}, {2.001, 4.4901, 
  1.00001}, {2.001, 4.9901, 1.00001}, {2.001, 5.4901, 
  1.00001}, {2.001, 5.9901, 1.00001}, {2.001, 6.4901, 
  1.00001}, {2.001, 6.9901, 1.00001}, {2.001, 7.4901, 
  1.00001}, {2.001, 7.9901, 1.00001}, {2.501, 1.4901, 
  1.00003}, {2.501, 1.9901, 1.00002}, {2.501, 2.4901, 
  1.00002}, {2.501, 2.9901, 1.00002}, {2.501, 3.4901, 
  1.00002}, {2.501, 3.9901, 1.00002}, {2.501, 4.4901, 
  1.00002}, {2.501, 4.9901, 1.00002}, {2.501, 5.4901, 
  1.00002}, {2.501, 5.9901, 1.00002}, {2.501, 6.4901, 
  1.00002}, {2.501, 6.9901, 1.00002}, {2.501, 7.4901, 
  1.00002}, {2.501, 7.9901, 1.00002}, {3.001, 1.9901, 
  1.00004}, {3.001, 2.4901, 1.00004}, {3.001, 2.9901, 
  1.00004}, {3.001, 3.4901, 1.00004}, {3.001, 3.9901, 
  1.00004}, {3.001, 4.4901, 1.00004}, {3.001, 4.9901, 
  1.00004}, {3.001, 5.4901, 1.00004}, {3.001, 5.9901, 
  1.00004}, {3.001, 6.4901, 1.00004}, {3.001, 6.9901, 
  1.00004}, {3.001, 7.4901, 1.00004}, {3.001, 7.9901, 
  1.00004}, {3.501, 1.9901, 1.00008}, {3.501, 2.4901, 
  1.00007}, {3.501, 2.9901, 1.00007}, {3.501, 3.4901, 
  1.00007}, {3.501, 3.9901, 1.00006}, {3.501, 4.4901, 
  1.00006}, {3.501, 4.9901, 1.00006}, {3.501, 5.4901, 
  1.00006}, {3.501, 5.9901, 1.00006}, {3.501, 6.4901, 
  1.00006}, {3.501, 6.9901, 1.00006}, {3.501, 7.4901, 
  1.00006}, {3.501, 7.9901, 1.00006}, {4.001, 1.9901, 
  1.00012}, {4.001, 2.4901, 1.00012}, {4.001, 2.9901, 
  1.00011}, {4.001, 3.4901, 1.00011}, {4.001, 3.9901, 1.0001}, {4.001,
   4.4901, 1.0001}, {4.001, 4.9901, 1.0001}, {4.001, 5.4901, 
  1.0001}, {4.001, 5.9901, 1.00009}, {4.001, 6.4901, 1.00009}, {4.001,
   6.9901, 1.00009}, {4.001, 7.4901, 1.00009}, {4.001, 7.9901, 
  1.00009}, {4.501, 1.9901, 1.00019}, {4.501, 2.4901, 
  1.00017}, {4.501, 2.9901, 1.00017}, {4.501, 3.4901, 
  1.00016}, {4.501, 3.9901, 1.00015}, {4.501, 4.4901, 
  1.00015}, {4.501, 4.9901, 1.00015}, {4.501, 5.4901, 
  1.00014}, {4.501, 5.9901, 1.00014}, {4.501, 6.4901, 
  1.00014}, {4.501, 6.9901, 1.00014}, {4.501, 7.4901, 
  1.00013}, {4.501, 7.9901, 1.00013}, {5.001, 2.4901, 
  1.00025}, {5.001, 2.9901, 1.00024}, {5.001, 3.4901, 
  1.00023}, {5.001, 3.9901, 1.00022}, {5.001, 4.4901, 
  1.00022}, {5.001, 4.9901, 1.00021}, {5.001, 5.4901, 
  1.00021}, {5.001, 5.9901, 1.0002}, {5.001, 6.4901, 1.0002}, {5.001, 
  6.9901, 1.00019}, {5.001, 7.4901, 1.00019}, {5.001, 7.9901, 
  1.00019}, {5.501, 2.4901, 1.00035}, {5.501, 2.9901, 
  1.00034}, {5.501, 3.4901, 1.00032}, {5.501, 3.9901, 
  1.00031}, {5.501, 4.4901, 1.0003}, {5.501, 4.9901, 1.00029}, {5.501,
   5.4901, 1.00029}, {5.501, 5.9901, 1.00028}, {5.501, 6.4901, 
  1.00027}, {5.501, 6.9901, 1.00027}, {5.501, 7.4901, 
  1.00026}, {5.501, 7.9901, 1.00026}, {6.001, 2.4901, 
  1.00048}, {6.001, 2.9901, 1.00045}, {6.001, 3.4901, 
  1.00044}, {6.001, 3.9901, 1.00042}, {6.001, 4.4901, 
  1.00041}, {6.001, 4.9901, 1.0004}, {6.001, 5.4901, 1.00039}, {6.001,
   5.9901, 1.00038}, {6.001, 6.4901, 1.00037}, {6.001, 6.9901, 
  1.00036}, {6.001, 7.4901, 1.00036}, {6.001, 7.9901, 
  1.00035}, {6.501, 2.9901, 1.0006}, {6.501, 3.4901, 1.00057}, {6.501,
   3.9901, 1.00055}, {6.501, 4.4901, 1.00054}, {6.501, 4.9901, 
  1.00052}, {6.501, 5.4901, 1.00051}, {6.501, 5.9901, 1.0005}, {6.501,
   6.4901, 1.00049}, {6.501, 6.9901, 1.00048}, {6.501, 7.4901, 
  1.00047}, {6.501, 7.9901, 1.00046}, {7.001, 2.9901, 
  1.00077}, {7.001, 3.4901, 1.00074}, {7.001, 3.9901, 
  1.00071}, {7.001, 4.4901, 1.00069}, {7.001, 4.9901, 
  1.00067}, {7.001, 5.4901, 1.00065}, {7.001, 5.9901, 
  1.00064}, {7.001, 6.4901, 1.00063}, {7.001, 6.9901, 
  1.00062}, {7.001, 7.4901, 1.0006}, {7.001, 7.9901, 1.00059}, {7.501,
   2.9901, 1.00096}, {7.501, 3.4901, 1.00092}, {7.501, 3.9901, 
  1.00089}, {7.501, 4.4901, 1.00087}, {7.501, 4.9901, 
  1.00085}, {7.501, 5.4901, 1.00083}, {7.501, 5.9901, 
  1.00081}, {7.501, 6.4901, 1.00079}, {7.501, 6.9901, 
  1.00078}, {7.501, 7.4901, 1.00076}, {7.501, 7.9901, 
  1.00075}, {8.001, 2.9901, 1.00117}, {8.001, 3.4901, 
  1.00114}, {8.001, 3.9901, 1.0011}, {8.001, 4.4901, 1.00107}, {8.001,
   4.9901, 1.00104}, {8.001, 5.4901, 1.00102}, {8.001, 5.9901, 
  1.001}, {8.001, 6.4901, 1.00098}, {8.001, 6.9901, 1.00096}, {8.001, 
  7.4901, 1.00095}, {8.001, 7.9901, 1.00093}, {8.501, 2.9901, 
  1.00141}, {8.501, 3.4901, 1.00137}, {8.501, 3.9901, 
  1.00133}, {8.501, 4.4901, 1.0013}, {8.501, 4.9901, 1.00127}, {8.501,
   5.4901, 1.00124}, {8.501, 5.9901, 1.00121}, {8.501, 6.4901, 
  1.00119}, {8.501, 6.9901, 1.00117}, {8.501, 7.4901, 
  1.00115}, {8.501, 7.9901, 1.00113}, {9.001, 3.4901, 
  1.00162}, {9.001, 3.9901, 1.00158}, {9.001, 4.4901, 
  1.00154}, {9.001, 4.9901, 1.00151}, {9.001, 5.4901, 
  1.00148}, {9.001, 5.9901, 1.00145}, {9.001, 6.4901, 
  1.00142}, {9.001, 6.9901, 1.0014}, {9.001, 7.4901, 1.00138}, {9.001,
   7.9901, 1.00136}, {9.501, 3.4901, 1.00189}, {9.501, 3.9901, 
  1.00185}, {9.501, 4.4901, 1.00181}, {9.501, 4.9901, 
  1.00177}, {9.501, 5.4901, 1.00174}, {9.501, 5.9901, 
  1.00171}, {9.501, 6.4901, 1.00168}, {9.501, 6.9901, 
  1.00165}, {9.501, 7.4901, 1.00163}, {9.501, 7.9901, 
  1.00161}, {10.001, 3.4901, 1.00218}, {10.001, 3.9901, 
  1.00213}, {10.001, 4.4901, 1.00209}, {10.001, 4.9901, 
  1.00205}, {10.001, 5.4901, 1.00201}, {10.001, 5.9901, 
  1.00198}, {10.001, 6.4901, 1.00195}, {10.001, 6.9901, 
  1.00192}, {10.001, 7.4901, 1.00189}, {10.001, 7.9901, 
  1.00187}, {10.501, 3.4901, 1.00247}, {10.501, 3.9901, 
  1.00243}, {10.501, 4.4901, 1.00238}, {10.501, 4.9901, 
  1.00234}, {10.501, 5.4901, 1.0023}, {10.501, 5.9901, 
  1.00227}, {10.501, 6.4901, 1.00223}, {10.501, 6.9901, 
  1.0022}, {10.501, 7.4901, 1.00218}, {10.501, 7.9901, 
  1.00215}, {11.001, 3.4901, 1.00278}, {11.001, 3.9901, 
  1.00273}, {11.001, 4.4901, 1.00268}, {11.001, 4.9901, 
  1.00264}, {11.001, 5.4901, 1.0026}, {11.001, 5.9901, 
  1.00257}, {11.001, 6.4901, 1.00253}, {11.001, 6.9901, 
  1.0025}, {11.001, 7.4901, 1.00247}, {11.001, 7.9901, 
  1.00244}, {11.501, 3.4901, 1.0031}, {11.501, 3.9901, 
  1.00304}, {11.501, 4.4901, 1.003}, {11.501, 4.9901, 
  1.00295}, {11.501, 5.4901, 1.00291}, {11.501, 5.9901, 
  1.00287}, {11.501, 6.4901, 1.00284}, {11.501, 6.9901, 
  1.00281}, {11.501, 7.4901, 1.00278}, {11.501, 7.9901, 
  1.00275}, {12.001, 3.4901, 1.00342}, {12.001, 3.9901, 
  1.00336}, {12.001, 4.4901, 1.00331}, {12.001, 4.9901, 
  1.00327}, {12.001, 5.4901, 1.00323}, {12.001, 5.9901, 
  1.00319}, {12.001, 6.4901, 1.00315}, {12.001, 6.9901, 
  1.00312}, {12.001, 7.4901, 1.00309}, {12.001, 7.9901, 
  1.00306}, {12.501, 3.4901, 1.00374}, {12.501, 3.9901, 
  1.00369}, {12.501, 4.4901, 1.00364}, {12.501, 4.9901, 
  1.00359}, {12.501, 5.4901, 1.00355}, {12.501, 5.9901, 
  1.00351}, {12.501, 6.4901, 1.00347}, {12.501, 6.9901, 
  1.00344}, {12.501, 7.4901, 1.00341}, {12.501, 7.9901, 1.00338}}
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Have you tried adding `PlotRange -> All`?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, but it is not useful.

Comment: Using `InterpolationOrder -> 0` it somehow works, but I don't know why. Waiting for better answers.

Comment: I have tried that. It does not work. Thank you. @H.Zhou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is an extended comment rather than an answer.**

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)
```

[`ListDensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html) appears to cover the convex hull of the data points.

```
Show[
 ListDensityPlot[
  datadensity],
 ListPlot[
  Most /@ datadensity,
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Defining a region (`reg`) that excludes the portions of the convex hull that do not contain data points.

```
Show[
 Region[
  reg = RegionUnion @@
    (ConvexHullRegion /@
      (Flatten[#, 1] & /@
        Partition[
         SplitBy[Most /@ datadensity,
          First], 2, 1])),
  Axes -> True],
 ListPlot[
  Most /@ datadensity,
  PlotStyle -> Red],
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

However, using `reg` to define the `RegionFunction` doesn't change the `ListDensityPlot`

```
Show[
 ListDensityPlot[
  datadensity,
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, f}, {x, y} \[Element] reg]],
 ListPlot[
  Most /@ datadensity,
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Similarly,

```
Show[
 ListDensityPlot[
  datadensity,
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, f}, RegionMember[reg, {x, y}]]],
 ListPlot[
  Most /@ datadensity,
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
(* same plot *)
```